# MSSQL to MySQL Migrations

Tags: mysql, sql, migration

I am trying to figure out how to reconstruct the following sql to the proper migration to Mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE [LinkedAccountClaims](
[UserAccountID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ProviderName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
[ProviderAccountID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Value] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_LinkedAccountClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UserAccountID] ASC,
[ProviderName] ASC,
[ProviderAccountID] ASC,
[Type] ASC,
[Value] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserAccountID] ON [LinkedAccountClaims]
(   [UserAccountID] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [LinkedAccountClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_LinkedAccountClaims_UserAccounts_UserAccountID] FOREIGN KEY([UserAccountID])
REFERENCES [UserAccounts] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

to a migration which is structured as follows

```
CreateTable(
            "LinkedAccountClaims",
            c => new
            {
                UserAccountID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 38, storeType: "char"),
                ProviderName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 30, storeType: "nvarchar"),
                ProviderAccountID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100, storeType: "nvarchar"),
                Type = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150, storeType: "nvarchar"),
                Value = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150, storeType: "nvarchar"),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserAccountID)
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProviderName)
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProviderAccountID)
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Type)
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Value)
            .Index(t => t.UserAccountID);
```

I am not certain I am doing the primary key clustering properly in the migration and I'm not sure how to handle the foreign key.

**UPDATE:**
That is properly clustering the primary keys and to add a foregin key you use code like so

```
 .ForeignKey("UserAccounts", t => t.UserAccountID, cascadeDelete: true)
```

Comment: that is not MySQL `create table` statement. What you have here is LINQ query. So what is your question?

Comment: That is a sql migration to a mysql database. It creates the tables fine but im doing the foreign keys manually. I want to know how to do it in that linq migration code and if the way Im handling the primary keys does set them up as a cluster as the sql shows.

Comment: I would not do it in LINQ, I'm sure someone might find a way to do it in LINQ but for this you should just write MySQL create table syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: Except that this is being done as part of a large msssql to mysql migration and doing it by hand in mysql syntax would take a long time, the majority of the code is generated aytomatically by the migration i just need to add the foreignkeys and make sure the primarys are correct. It would have been helpful had you LOOKED at what I asked as the issue as now less people are apt to respond

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is little bit different in syntax and support with others try this. don't use multiple primary key in table

```
    CREATE TABLE LinkedAccountClaims(
UserAccountID int unique NOT NULL ,
ProviderName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
ProviderAccountID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Type varchar(150) NOT NULL,
Value varchar(150) NOT NULL,
primary key (UserAccountID)
);

CREATE INDEX IX_UserAccountID ON LinkedAccountClaims
(UserAccountID);

ALTER TABLE LinkedAccountClaims ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_LinkedAccountClaims_UserAccounts_UserAccountID FOREIGN KEY(UserAccountID)
REFERENCES UserAccounts(ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work in workbench BUT I am doing it in migrations. I've sorted it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a transformation using Pentaho Data Integration?